# UIIMagePickerController dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to pick an image from UIImagePickerController and then set it inline inside UITextView. The code below is pretty straightforward. When i tap "act" button, it opens up UIImagePickerController and once it's done, the delegate method `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` gets triggered.

```
- (IBAction)act:(id)sender{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    if(!self.imageView){
        self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:chosenImage];
        [self.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        [self.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 100.0f, 100.0f)];
        [self.content addSubview:self.imageView];
        UIBezierPath *exclusionPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,120.0f,110.0f)];
        self.content.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[exclusionPath];

    } else {
        [self.imageView setImage:chosenImage];
    }
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Here's the problem: when i try to dismiss UIImagePickerViewController using `dismissViewController`, it is just ignored. However, it works fine without the two lines where i'm setting the exclusionPaths. Also, this only happens when there's already text in the UITextView. If there's no text, I can do this as many times as I want and dismissViewController works fine. I've stepped through the code and the code actually does pass through the `[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated: completion:` line. Also `picker` at that point is indeed an instance of UIImagePickerController. Anyone have idea what is going on?

[UPDATE] I've actually trimmed down the code to the following:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIBezierPath *exclusionPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,120.0f,110.0f)];
    self.content.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[exclusionPath];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Basically I don't even set the imageView anymore. It's just that when I try to set the exclusionPaths of a UITextView--`self.content`--the `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` doesn't work. There is no error in the console.

Comment: Is your statement *"it just doesn't get ignored"* a typo?

Comment: Yes sorry it was a typo. I've updated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `dismissViewConroller:` on `self` and not `picker`.

Better yet, call it on `picker.presentingViewController` like this:

```
[picker.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Yes I've tried all of those options. The problem is that in normal cases all of them work, but when I try to set the exclusionPaths property of the UITextView inside the presenting view controller it just crashes--by crashing I mean the screen stays still but doesn't react to interaction anymore, and no error logs.

Comment: Ok, so what is `content` property?

Comment: It's a property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *content;

Comment: Ok, what if you simply dismiss it as the first line of the function? Dismiss, and **then** set the exclusion path

Comment: Nope. I've even tried wrapping it inside the completion block. What happens is: it works the first time. But when i open up the picker again and try to pick another image, the code doesn't even reach the completion block. It's that one line             `self.content.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[exclusionPath];`
that's causing the problem. If I take that out, the picker works fine (although i then don't have the exclusion path anymore of course)